# Synchronize Blackberry Address book and Calendar with Evolution Directly

Tags: evolution, sync, blackberry

Are there any applications available that can be used to safely synchronize a Blackberry smart phone directly with Evolution?

I use some tools made available by barry-util from the repository, I am able to charge my Blackberry Curve 8300 via USB, I can also backup the address book and calendar to computer disk, however, I would like to know if there are any tools available to synchronise these types of phones directly with Evolution, I heard about a library called opensync and I am guessing that it can be used with barry to accomplish what I want.

I am presently synchronizing my phone with Google, see this: http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/ I then export data from my Google web applications to use in Evolution, this is not as smooth as I would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing which is easy, basically what you must do is install the latest version of libbarry opensync (0.4x) opensync-barry and opensync-eds (evolution data services) then you can use the command line to make a configuration for your blackberry adding in the id of the phone which you can grab using barry-utils.

Then you use the command line to make a sync between the two.

Now I must warn you that the likelyhood of loosing data is very high, blackberries and evolution are not nice PIMs and aren't standardised.

Your other option is to use the ubuntu one phone syncing service which apparently works quite well. https://one.ubuntu.com/mobile/ but that costs money.

Comment: In the future that is, especially since Ubuntu one contacts can be made available in Evo. via CouchDB (not working well yet), for now I will stay with the clunky Google sync method.