# BlackBerry Desktop Manager for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, blackberry

How do i backup  and sync my BlackBerry Mobile in Ubuntu 12.04

Are there any application available for the same??

Also, I am unable to set up my email on the BlackBerry Mobile, what could be the problem?

The set-up for e-mail is not appearing in set-up applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options, but none of them are easy, and chances for data loss are high.

[Please read this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87914/blackberry-and-ubuntu-as-easy-to-connect?rq=1) and it's links,  [and this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12503/synchronize-blackberry-address-book-and-calendar-with-evolution-directly?rq=1) about syncing with evolution.

As for the setup of the email on the blackberry it's self, there's not a lot this forum can help you with. Blackberry configurations are very varied. IT, Telco, and you all have options to enable and disable pretty much every feature on the phone. I know many IT departments that disable "email setup" so that users have to go though corporate to get their blackberries setup. I also know a few telco providers that  disable it so that you have to go through their setup method (though I don't exactly know why).

There is also the question of BIS or BES. Most consumers use a free BIS provided by their telco provider.

I have found [Crackberry Fourms](http://forums.crackberry.com/) to be quite helpful. You may try your blackberry support issues there.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah right but you have to pay the rupees of BIS(Blackberry Internet Service) and BES(Blackberry Enterprise System) plan.

Plan price estimate 399 and 899 INR.

And all the data are stored in Blackberry Server not your ubuntu desktop.

Blackberry Data to Back Up using Blackberry Protect

> Contacts
>   Calenders
>   Tasks
>   Memos
>   Browser's Bookmarks
>   Text Messages
>   Password Keeper Database
>   Wi-Fi Network Profiles

Answer (score 1):

Install this software in your ubuntu desktop

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/04/manage-your-blackberry-smartphone-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install XP or W7 as a virtual machine under VirtualBox under Ubuntu, that way, you have an easy way to run all sorts of software that you can't run directly under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Linberry? It's almost the same as the original desktop software but intended for Linux, so you will be able to transfer data between your Linux and your Blackberry. And of course, it's free. 
;-)

Comment: May be, someone using BB can try this. I ain't a BB user anymore, and probably not many left in the world either ;)